# Relative path of a file needed by a jar inside a web project

Tags: java, web-services, filepath

I've written an application which uses sql script from a text file. I've put the .txt file in the project root folder.

[image]

After I've exported the project into a jar and put it in /lib folder inside a web project. The process that uses the .txt file can't find It.

[image]

Where to put the file?

Comment: You should load this file as a classpath resource, not as a bona fide file.

Comment: can you reference me to some example, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in the context of a webapp, or any running jar for that matter, *do not* use filesystem resources; they can only work in your IDE environment.

Use this instead (for example; there are other ways to do this):

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static final URL RESOURCE_URL;

    static {
        RESOURCE_URL = MyClass.class.getResource("/my/resource");
        if (RESOURCE_URL == null)
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("/my/resource not found");
    }
    // bla bla...

    // code to load from the resource:

    try (
        final InputStream in = RESOURCE_URL.openStream();
        // others, as needed
    ) {
        // work here
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the difference between stating the path in File and stating it in the resource. Please refer to the TABLE.txt as seen in the pictures.

Comment: Do you think there will be a _file_ named `TABLE.txt` when you package your webapp as a war? No. Will there be a resource for it? Yes. You should use that which is a file in your IDE as a resource, since when the webapp will run, _it will not_ be a file. As to where to put it, put it in the resources directory for your webapp (where this is located is project dependent, but it's usually in `src/main/resources`).